# VHDL test bench error please help, for school

Tags: vhdl

im trying to make a test bench for this program, but it says "Physical unit hidden by declaration of 'w' at line 6."
It's a project for school, and i really cant find out why it doesn't work..
thanks!

The program:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY comp IS
GENERIC (W : NATURAL  );  
PORT (A_v     :IN  std_logic_vector((W-1) DOWNTO 0); --vector a aan ingang
      B_v     :IN  std_logic_vector((W-1) DOWNTO 0); --vector b aan ingang
            groter   :OUT std_logic;  --led 'groter' actief indien a>b
            gelijk   :OUT std_logic);  --led 'gelijk' actief indien a==b
END comp;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF comp IS

--SIGNAL ci1, ci2: std_logic;
BEGIN
proc: PROCESS (A_v,B_v)
BEGIN

if (A_v=B_v) then
groter<='0';
gelijk<='1';

elsif (A_v>B_v) then
groter<='1';
gelijk<='0';

else
groter<='0';
gelijk<='0';
end if;


END PROCESS proc;

END behavior;
```

---

### the test bench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY comp_test IS
generic (w : NATURAL := 5);  
END comp_test;

ARCHITECTURE structural OF comp_test IS 

-- Unit Under Test: uut
    COMPONENT comp 
generic (w : NATURAL); 
PORT (A_v     :IN  std_logic_vector(w-1 DOWNTO 0); --vector a aan ingang
      B_v     :IN  std_logic_vector(w-1 DOWNTO 0); --vector b aan ingang
            groter   :OUT std_logic;  --led 'groter' actief indien a>b
            gelijk   :OUT std_logic);  --led 'gelijk' actief indien a==b

    END COMPONENT;

  FOR uut: comp USE ENTITY work.comp(behavior);

    CONSTANT period : time := 100 ns;
  SIGNAL   end_of_sim : boolean := false;

-- NATURALerconnection (signals - ports)
SIGNAL A_v     :  std_logic_vector(w-1 DOWNTO 0); --vector a aan ingang
SIGNAL B_v     :std_logic_vector(w-1 DOWNTO 0); --vector b aan ingang
SIGNAL  groter   : std_logic;  --led 'groter' actief indien a>b
SIGNAL  gelijk   : std_logic;  --led 'gelijk' actief indien a==b

BEGIN

    uut : comp 
    GENERIC MAP (w=>5 )
    PORT MAP(
        A_v   => A_v,
        B_v   => B_v,
        groter => groter,
        gelijk => gelijk

    );

-- Test Bench: TVI-generator
   tb_gen : PROCESS
  VARIABLE i_v: std_logic_vector((2w-1) DOWNTO 0);

  BEGIN

  FOR i IN 0 TO (2**2w-1)
  LOOP
    A_v<=i_v(2w-1 downto w);
  B_v<=i_v(w-1 downto 0);
    i_v:=i_v+1;
    wait for period;
  END LOOP;
  end_of_sim <= true;
  WAIT;
  END PROCESS tb_gen;
END structural;
```

Comment: please be aware: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Please add some more detail as to what you've done so far to try and solve this problem on your own :)

Answer (score 2):

I warn you ... you'll kick yourself!

`VARIABLE i_v: std_logic_vector((2w-1) DOWNTO 0);`

The error message is telling you that a physical quantity comprising a value and a physical unit (like 2 ns, 2 ms, or ... 2 W), cannot be parsed because a declaration of W hides the alleged physical unit!

If there was no declaration of W you would see a different error (no declaration of such a physical unit - mw w kw etc could be legally declared, to represent power, the same way ns etc are pre-declared to represent time.)

Whereas ...

you were aiming to multiply `w` by 2 ... as in

`VARIABLE i_v: std_logic_vector((2*w - 1) DOWNTO 0);`

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a clear error message, however, I do not see enough code to determine what the overlap is.

The fix is simple.  Change the name of your generic whose name is "w" to something longer, such as "gWIDTH".  Note that the name WIDTH is used in the package "std.textio.all ;"

Here is a little complete example of something that may be a little more obvious:

```
architecture test1 of testbench is
   signal NS : time ; 
     . . .

begin
  MainTestProc : process
  begin
    . . . 
    wait for 5 ns ; --<<--  Error 
    . . .
```

In "wait for 5 ns ;" the signal declaration "NS" is in the local scope.  Hence, the unit of time is not visible and the resulting error is most often at best confusing.

Comment: See Brian's discussion also.  The 2W is it.  Although, that should have errored too as a space is required between the digits and units.  Given that W is a unit of a physical unit, I would also follow my hints above about changing the name "W".

Comment: I wonder if the current error is masking the "missing space" error ... or if he is using one of those tools that doesn't report the missing space.